# How to show that if $A^{T}A\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{0}$ then $A\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{0}$

Tags: linear-algebra

I am self studying from Kuttler's *Linear Algebra, Theory, and Applications* and one of the problems hints that I should try to show that if $A^{T}A\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{0}$ then $A\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{0}$. I have been at it for a while with nothing to show for it. How can I prove this?

Comment: Hint: multiply by $\textbf{x}^T$ on the left and do some manipulation, and use the properties of the dot product.

Comment: i. ${\bf x} \cdot (A{\bf y})=( A^t {\bf x}) \cdot {\bf y}$ (check!); ii. ${\bf z} \cdot {\bf z}=0$ iff ${\bf z}=0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $$A^{t}Ax=0 \implies x^{t}A^{t}Ax=0 \implies ||Ax||^{2}=\langle (Ax)^{t},Ax \rangle=x^{t}A^{t}Ax=0 \implies Ax=0$$

Answer (score 1):

$\langle A^TA(x)\rangle=\langle A(x),A(x)\rangle=0$

Comment: What is $<A^TA(x)>$?

Comment: @JCAA inner product.

Comment: Should be $\langle x, A^TA x\rangle=0=\langle Ax, Ax\rangle=||Ax||^2$. hence $Ax=0$.

Comment: Yes, you're right!

Comment: @Ramanujan: Inner products have two arguments.

Comment: ah, sorry I was thinking about $\langle A^{t},Ax\rangle$

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are dealing with real matrices, note that if $A^T A \mathbf{x} = \mathbf{0}$, then $A \mathbf{x}$ must be in the null space of $A^T$, which in particular is orthogonal to the row space of $A^T$ (and hence orthogonal to the column space of $A$). But $A \mathbf{x}$ is by construction in the column space of $A$!

All this is to show that $A \mathbf{x}$ is both in the column space of $A$ and the space orthogonal to the column space of $A$. These two facts together imply that $A \mathbf{x} = \mathbf{0}$.

Answer (score 1):

If $A^{T}Ax = 0$ then $x^{T}A^{T}Ax = x^{T}0 = 0$. Thus:
$$x^{T}A^{T}Ax = (Ax)^{T}Ax = ||Ax||^{2} = 0$$
This implies $Ax = 0$.